# Nim websocket client using threads instead of async

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, process, nim-lang

Is there a possibility to use websockets in nim with threads instead of async - or handle input- and output streams with async instead of threads?

I try to redirect the input and output streams of a process to websocket messages. Whenever I get a message from a websocket server, I want to redirect it to the input stream of the process and when the process writes to the output stream, this should be redirected as a message to the websocket server.

I'm able to send messages to the server with the treeform/ws library, but this library is using async and I'm able to handle the input and output streams with threads but I can't figure out how to bring 'em together

```
import asyncdispatch, ws, streams, os, osproc

proc readOutput(sock: Websocket, output: Stream): Future[void] {.async.} =
  while sock.readyState == Open:
    echo "entering output-read loop"
    var line: string
    while output.readLine(line):
      echo "Line: " & line
    echo "output done"

proc readInput(sock: Websocket, input: Stream): Future[void] {.async.} =
  while sock.readyState == Open:
    echo "entering input-read loop"
    var inp = await sock.receiveStrPacket()
    if inp == "":
      break
    echo "Input received: " & inp
    input.writeLine(inp)
    input.flush()
    echo "input done"


proc main() {.async.} = 
  # open process
  var p = startProcess("program.exe", options={poUsePath, poStdErrToStdOut, poEvalCommand, poDaemon})
  var input = p.inputStream()
  var output = p.outputStream()

  # open websocket
  var sock = await newWebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8888/ws/imp")

  waitFor readInput(sock, input)
  waitFor readOutput(sock, output)

waitFor main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another Websocket library called "[guzba/whisky](https://github.com/guzba/whisky)".
this one does not use async but it blocks.

```
import whisky, options

let ws = newWebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9001/ws")
while true:
  let optmsg = ws.receiveMessage()
  if optmsg.isSome:
    let msg = optmsg.get()
    if msg.kind == TextMessage:
      echo "Got: " & msg.data
      ws.send("HI")
```